# how to set minimum quantity of products in the shopping cart?

Tags: commerce

I want to set minimum quantity of goods that customer may order in the shop. For example minimum quantity is 20, so if customer order less then 20 his order won't process and there will be message telling him that he must purchase 20 or more and redirecting him to his shopping cart

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Commerce Minimum Order Quantity and Increment](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/artis/1808850) sandbox module.

> The module allow you set minimum order quantity and an order quantity
>   increment. This quantity is for the entire order not each product line
>   item. Your shoppers will not be able to check out until their order
>   quantiy reaches the minimum and/or meets the increment.
>
> Download this module and install it. Go to admin/commerce/config/moqi
>   to config.

<sup>Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/drupal_modules/status/256080330564464642)</sup>

Comment: as I see in this module there isn't possibility to set minimum order quantity per product type

Comment: @rick1 you probably just have to modify an if statement to add that functionality.

Comment: where can I add this? can I do the same with rules module?